# На каком основании тут поставлена запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть одно предложение, пунктуация которого мне смутила. :)

"Мы с Гермионой все видели. Он смотрел на тебя, не отводя глаз, и шептал заклинания".

Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, почему поставлена запятая перед союзом **и**?

Все же один субъект, тогда зачем тут запятая?

Я был бы благодарен, если бы Вы в доступной для меня форме объяснили, прав ли я или нет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он смотрел на тебя, не отводя глаз, и шептал заклинания.

Здесь союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые, обособление деепричастного оборота, отнесенного к первому сказуемому.